# date field is not rendered in template-Django

Tags: django

I am using a model form in app,

models.py

```
class Report(models.Model):
    manual_date_time = models.DateTimeField('Another time', null=True, blank=True)
```

modelform.py is

```
class ReportForm(forms.ModelForm):   
    class Meta:
        model = Report
        fields = ['incident_description','manual_date_time', 'location_description',
                  'incident_followup', 'incident_followup_name_1', 'incident_followup_email_1', 
                  'incident_followup_name_2', 'incident_followup_email_2', 'phone_call_log', 
                  'notes_other','notes_firstaid','notes_risk']

class ReportPersonForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = ReportPerson
        fields = ['name','first_aid','sick_bay','ambulance']
```

template is

In my template, I used the below code to render the field but field area is not shown in template.

```
{{ form.manual_date_time }}
```

views.py

```
def when(request):

    return render(request, 'incident/when.html',
                  {
                   'newreport_menu': True,
                 })
```

May I know what I did wrong?

Comment: Can you show your code to populate template variables, e.g. `form`?

Comment: i updated my form above.Thansk

Comment: That's not what I mean.  I was talking about the code in `views.py` with `render` or similar function called.

Comment: With which name did you pass your form object to your template from your views? Django will not raise an exception if `form` is not anexisting object while calling `{{ form.manual_date_time }}`

Comment: functionality in views.py not yet written,I was created a views method  to render teh page.i am in mark-up design,so to render the field i am looking for form.

Comment: Well than, you must first send your `form object` to your template within `context dictionary` otherwise, you can not render it in there...

Comment: show us the views method :) even if it does nothing to the form, would be helpful to see it :D

Comment: @SamueleMattiuzzo i updated my question with views method

Comment: @FallenAngel I am new to django how to send the form object to the template within context dictionary.Any example will do.Thanks

Comment: You better start reading tutorials... [Here tells](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/forms/#using-a-form-in-a-view) how you should pass your form object to your template from your view.

But I guess, It is better to check the whole [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/)

Comment: ya i got it how to pass.Thansk

Comment: @user2086641 as I said, you must read the whole section, that link which shows how to pass form to template is somewhat starting from the middle of the topic.

Comment: Voted to close as too localized since OP do not read the docs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

django doesn't magically put your form in your page...

```
def when(request):

    form = ReportForm()

    return render(request, 'incident/when.html',
              {
               'form': form,
               'newreport_menu': True,
             })
```

now you have a context element called `form` which you can reference in your template with `{{ form }}`